# debugging node-red module in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, nodeclipse, node-red

i installed **node-red** and will debug into the node-red module '99-sample.js'.
Therefor i installed **nodeclipse**. I can step to the line with the code
`module.exports = function(RED) { .. }` 
but i can't step into the module although is set a breakpoint in there.
The debugger is starting with:

```
node --debug-brk=5858 ./99-sample.js
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can step in to `99-sample.js`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to execute the 99-sample.js file? you need to run red.js which will load the 99-sample.js later

Comment: Hey thanks :D,  it works. I installed **$ npm installer -g node-inspector** and start it with **$ node-debug /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js** . The debugger starts in the browser. Now you can open the menubar **Source > file:// > nodes > 99-sample.js** to added a breakpoint. Maybe you must open node-red in the Browser and **deploy** your flow to stop on your breakpoint.